# Cronômetro sendo executado apartir do primeiro segundo

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

Galera encontrei esse código em um fórum, fiz algumas modificações só que não sei por que o script só está sendo executado depois de 1 segundo, por exemplo... ele funciona normal atualizando depois de 1s, só que ele não mostra o primeiro segundo, entenderam? a printagem dos valores na tela vem depois do primeiro segundo... Parece coisa simples, só que não sou muito bom em JS, fucei fucei e não consegui fazer funfa como quero!

**Detalhe: Necessita do jquery**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sem título</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var tempo = new Number();

// Tempo em segundos

tempo = 86400;

function startCountdown(){

// Se o tempo não for zerado

if((tempo - 1) >= 0){

// Pega a parte inteira dos minutos

var min = parseInt(tempo/60);

// horas, pega a parte inteira dos minutos
var hor = parseInt(min/60);

//atualiza a variável minutos obtendo o tempo restante dos minutos
min = min % 60;

// Calcula os segundos restantes
var seg = tempo%60;

// Formata o número menor que dez, ex: 08, 07, ...

if(min < 10){
min = "0"+min;

min = min.substr(0, 2);

}

if(seg <=9){
seg = "0"+seg;

}

if(hor <=9){
hor = "0"+hor;
}

// Cria a variável para formatar no estilo hora/cronômetro

horaImprimivel = hor+':' + min + ':' + seg;

//JQuery pra setar o valor

$("#sessao").html(horaImprimivel);

// Define que a função será executada novamente em 1000ms = 1 segundo

setTimeout('startCountdown()',1000);

// diminui o tempo

tempo--;

// Quando o contador chegar a zero faz esta ação

}
}

// Chama a função ao carregar a tela

startCountdown();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id='sessao'></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não deu pra entender. É um countdown de 1 em 1 segundo, logo ao rodar a função, irá começar após 1 segundo. Me parece tudo normal. O que vc esperaria que acontecesse?

Comment: Bom, é que tenho uma função de contagem via ajax e logo quando eu atualizo a pagina ela já printa e sai fazendo a contagem em tempo real, esperava o mesmo dessa função, como disse ela sim faz o que queria, só que a partir do 1 segundo, e entendo que também ela está programada para atualizar de 1 seg em 1 seg mas, o que gostaria de saber é se tem como eu já printar o primeiro seg antes da função esperar 1 seg para começar...

Comment: Mas já printa `24:00:00`... depois vai descendo: `23:59:59`...`23:59:58` e assim por diante.

Comment: Que estanho! aqui para mim fica branco e só aparece depois de 1s o valor 23:59:59 .... esta é a queixa!

Comment: Se vc testar apenas esse código em uma página separada, vc verá que funciona normal. O que pode estar acontecendo que vc não vê o 24:00:00 é o contexto onde vc está usando a função. Seria bom editar a pergunta e colocar exatamente onde e como você está fazendo isso, até porque vc diz que tem um Ajax no meio, e isso pode influenciar no funcionamento da contagem.

Comment: Olá fiz o teste aqui, abri um documento novo com a semântica html5 e nada vou editar a postagem para conferir exatamente como está!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90576/discussion-between-sam-and-caio-lourencon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que ao executar o script o elemento `#sessao` ainda não foi incluído no DOM. Com isso, no primeiro segundo a função não encontrou o elemento. Após o primeiro segundo o elemento já foi incluído o DOM e irá imprimir o tempo.

Inclua o código dentro da função `$(function(){});` para que o script só inicie quando o DOM estiver pronto.

E altere o setTimeout para:

```
setTimeout(startCountdown,1000);
```

Sem aspas e sem `()`, pois o primeiro argumento já representa a função em si.

```js
$(function(){

var tempo = new Number();

// Tempo em segundos

tempo = 86400;

function startCountdown(){

// Se o tempo não for zerado

if((tempo - 1) >= 0){

// Pega a parte inteira dos minutos

var min = parseInt(tempo/60);

// horas, pega a parte inteira dos minutos
var hor = parseInt(min/60);

//atualiza a variável minutos obtendo o tempo restante dos minutos
min = min % 60;

// Calcula os segundos restantes
var seg = tempo%60;

// Formata o número menor que dez, ex: 08, 07, ...

if(min < 10){
min = "0"+min;

min = min.substr(0, 2);

}

if(seg <=9){
seg = "0"+seg;

}

if(hor <=9){
hor = "0"+hor;
}

// Cria a variável para formatar no estilo hora/cronômetro

horaImprimivel = hor+':' + min + ':' + seg;

//JQuery pra setar o valor

$("#sessao").html(horaImprimivel);

// Define que a função será executada novamente em 1000ms = 1 segundo

setTimeout(startCountdown,1000);

// diminui o tempo

tempo--;

// Quando o contador chegar a zero faz esta ação

}
}

// Chama a função ao carregar a tela

startCountdown();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sessao"></div>
```

Comment: Funcionando maravilhosamente! Muito obrigado.